# Identifying files with special characters in its name in a terminal

Tags: terminal

Something strange happened today.
I was connected to an HP server with putty, and saw two files with exact same name:

> -rw-r--r--   1 hemantj            3368 Apr  1 12:47 test
>   -rw-r--r--   1 hemantj              20 Sep  1 12:47 test

It was very strange as you can't have files with the same name.

Later when I was connected with FileZilla I saw that there is some special
character at the end of the second file name.

My Question: is it possible to highlight special characters in the file name in a terminal?

I am connected to HP-UX and my shell is tcsh and ksh.

**EDIT:**

Thanks all for your reply but I think [Keymon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/550/keymon)'s [solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2182/identifying-files-with-spacial-characters-in-its-name-in-terminal/2188#2188) is the simplest and more portable.
+1 for all of you -- I learned a lot from your responses

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use this:

```
ls -l | less
```

Answer (score 5):

The fact that you're on HP-UX is really the problem. With the GNU tools available on most Linux distributions there are several options.

There is `ls -q`, which displays special characters as '?'. Or `-b` which displays octal codes instead.

Another option is `ls | cat -v`.

Also `find . -type f -ls`, which displays using escape codes by default.

Some of those might work on HP-UX, but I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

If you are lucky enough to have od,

```
ls -1 | od -xC
```

`ls -1` prints the filenames, separated by a newline. `od -xC` prints the input text in hexadecimal, with recognisable ascii characters displayed under each octet.

Sample output for three files, named 1, 2, 3:

```
0000000    310a    320a    330a
           1  \n   2  \n   3  \n
0000006
```

Sample output for two files, named 1 and '\n2':

```
0000000    0a32    0a31    0a00
          \n   2  \n   1  \n
0000005
```

Notice that there are three newlines for two files, and lexographically, "\n2" sorted before "1".

Answer (score 1):

this is not a real highlighting, but it might help to identify the characters:

```
# find . -type f -exec sh -c "hexdump -C <<<'{}'" \;
```

it might be constructed better. teach me ;)

Comment: no hexdump. :(  `hexdump:  not found`

Comment: BTW can you please explain what above command do ?

Comment: sure ;) `find` localizes all files in the directory and executes hexdump. `hexdump -C` shows the ascii-numbers of the filename on the left and the corresponding ascii-chars on the right. An example output is available at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_dump (6th sample). I did not know that HP-UX does not have a hexdump, sorry. Google said, the command `xd` can replace hexdump on HP-UX